# Use chromebook for students in class?

Tags: linux, chromebook

I have the project of buying cheap laptops for in-class exams. With a quick search on Google: `Ubuntu` on a Chromebook I found plenty of materials. So, I bought an Asus C204 (it was the cheapest, but yet still too powerful for what I want).

I rapidly found that ChromeOS is in fact very closed. The shell can only be accessed in developer mode and only Google accounts can access the device.

I would like to configure iptables and wpa to only connect to one Wi-Fi and access only one IP on the network (which will be the exam portal).

I didn't find any way to configure my Chromebook in such a way. I also tried Crouton with Ubuntu, but this doesn't replace Chrome OS. The student could still reboot the OS and log in as a guest.

I would like to either :

- Install Linux as the main system.
- Configure ChromeOS for my purpose.

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: To install Linux, your Chromebook will most likely [require](https://wiki.galliumos.org/Hardware_Compatibility) a firmware replacement and more, a job for  an enthusiast. It might be better choosing an [alternative](https://www.fosslinux.com/42399/top-10-budget-linux-laptops-2020-edition.htm).

Comment: Chrome OS in the sort of locked down setup you describe requires enterprise management. As this is for a school that is what you actually want. You do not want individual devices that need to be individually configured.

Comment: Like music2myear said, Chome OS devices are (Linux/Gentoo) appliances. It's a wasteful idea to start tinkering with individual machines, reinstalling their operating systems and start managing their updates and patches. You want to get in touch with someone who can show you how these are supposed to be managed: For Education https://edu.google.com/products/chromebooks/ For Companies https://chromeenterprise.google/os/grab-and-go-chromebooks/ Don't confuse Chromebooks with Raspberry Pis or DOS/Windows laptops.

Comment: To answer your question about converting a Chromebook to a regular Linux computer:   Yes for most Chromebooks this is done by updating the firmware following the directions here: https://mrchromebox.tech.  However models based on the IntelGemini Lake board like your Asus as well as ones using ARM CPU's aren't compatible.  See the Supported Devices page on that site for details.  BTW: Chromebooks from the last three or so years have native Linux app support and don't need developer mode.  This won't help you though because apps can't control networking settings.